xgboost - colsample_bylevel & colsample_bynode
I don't really understand the meaning of these xgboost parameters or how they differ:
If I specify exactly one of these parameters (not both at the same time),

colsample_bylevel=0.5
colsample_bynode=0.5

shouldn't the algorithms behave the same in both cases? Can you give me an example?

The names of the parameters actually are quite literal here.
If you split your tree "bylevel" with 0.5 it will take half of your features at each level of the tree by random for consideration
If you split your tree "bynode" this means that at each node split it will consider half.
Meaning that if you do both as 0.5 like in your example it would do the following at each level:

select 50% of features as set a for this level to consider while splitting
select 50% of features from a to consider for splitting the next node

They sound similar and do something similar in the sense of defining how many features should be considered for splitting but on different areas of the tree

So far so good (or bad). I still don't get it. You say - when specifying both - it would:


select 50% of features as set a for this level to consider while splitting


select 50% of features from a to consider for splitting
the next node


But then wouldn't it be the same as just specifying either colsample_bylevel=0.25 or colsample_bynode=0.25?

using 0.25 is not the same...let me give you an example or rather two to demonstrate. For both I'm using features f1 to f8:
Example 1 - using both = 0.5:
in your root node "bylevel" selects 50% of features that are considered for splitting: It selects f1, f2, f3, f4.
now since "bynode" is also 50% for splitting your actual root node out of f1, f2, f3, f4 another 50% get's selected by random. So for example f1, f2
At the next depth this starts again
"bylevel" now chooses f3, f4, f5, f6 to consider for splitting
"by node" chooses f4, f5 for the left node and f3, f6 for the right

Example 2 - using "bylevel" = 0.25: at your root node only 25% will get considered for splitting. f1, f2 are selected. And for by node all will now be used for split. At depth 1 a different 25% will be chosen. So maybe f3,f4 now.

In summary: using both together makes randomized selection two-steps and therefor you have more random selections over your tree while using one parameter only gives you one subsample across either your level or nodes. Followup question for you though: Is one parameter better than the other? What effect has it two use "bylevel" or "bynode" in terms of your resulting models?

First I tried with this explanation: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/xgboost-colsample-by-hyperparameters-explained-6c0bac1bdc1.
I think things are misrepresented there so avoid it! In the end I think I figured it out myself.
